# JWT Signing Method HS256 Golang

Tags: go, jwt, jwt-go

I have a question about JWT signing with method HS256 in Go. I'm using this import "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"

It doesn't require a secret key length >= 256 bits (32 bytes)?

Let's say I have an server application written in Golang which gives JWT signed with a secret key length of 16 bits. When I try to verify this JWT in the client application (that is written in Java) with the same secret key it gives me an error:

`io.jsonwebtoken.security.WeakKeyException: The specified key byte array is 16 bits which is not secure enough for any JWT HMAC-SHA algorithm.`

Well, this error makes sense since the secret key length is less than 256 bits, but how was it possible for the server application to generate a JWT signed with a secret key with a size less than 256 bits without giving an error?

Here is the function that creates the access token:

```golang
import(
    "time"

    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

func CreateToken(userid uint64) (string, error) {
    var err error
    //Creating Access Token
    atClaims := jwt.MapClaims{}
    atClaims["authorized"] = true
    atClaims["user_id"] = userid
    atClaims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 15).Unix()
    at := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, atClaims)
    token, err := at.SignedString([]byte("NRF"))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return token, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "standard" jwt library in Go. So to answer this question thoroughly we will need to see the server code, or which library the server is using.

The [`crypto/hmac`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/hmac) and [`crypto/hash`](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/) packages don't define any errors to be returned in any case. So key length checking, like you described, should be done by the caller. So it is not a matter of the language `go` does something. It's a matter of how the program is written.

If you want to learn more, you can browse different implementations on https://jwt.io/#libraries-io. (Manually filter by Go).

Comment: Hello @Tim, thanks for your answer. Here is the function that creates the access token:
`func CreateToken(userid uint64) (string, error) {
 var err error
 //Creating Access Token
 atClaims := jwt.MapClaims{}
 atClaims["authorized"] = true
 atClaims["user_id"] = userid
 atClaims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 15).Unix()
 at := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, atClaims)
 token, err := at.SignedString([]byte("NRF"))
 if err != nil {
  return "", err
 }
 return token, nil
}`

Comment: You should edit the question and add this code. And for instance, where does `jwt` come from? It should be some kind of import. Please edit the question to have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And perhaps you could find the answer you are looking for by browsing the code.

Comment: I'm using this import "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go".